# Change width of stacked bar outlines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change the bar outlines in ggplot on a grouped stacked bar plot but It is not working. Outlined below is my data and the code used to generate the plot

```
Zoop_df_Ab = structure(list(Type = c("Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton"), Analysis = c("Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance", 
"Abundance", "Abundance", "Abundance"), Lake = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("Lake N11", 
"Area 8", "East Lake", "Lake 3", "Lake D2/D3"), class = "factor"), 
    Season = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("July", "August", "September"
    ), class = "factor"), Class = c("Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", 
    "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", 
    "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", 
    "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Cyclopoida", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", 
    "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", 
    "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", 
    "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Rotifera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", 
    "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", 
    "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", 
    "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Cladocera", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", 
    "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", 
    "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida", 
    "Calanoida", "Calanoida", "Calanoida"), Value = c(37.39606612, 
    59.57278527, 16.21270563, 9.244357511, 14.8075331, 24.63599526, 
    28.56153483, 26.08193697, 32.46147611, 6.752578658, 22.9140767, 
    16.30218654, 73.85432267, 54.61320687, 45.65693399, 49.90858563, 
    27.17392301, 82.20711196, 77.23726152, 82.55976636, 72.82360653, 
    46.72579398, 64.44483152, 58.71230142, 70.99528648, 49.34729382, 
    79.41097209, 16.66922671, 31.98659116, 49.854156, 0.259983024, 
    0.733860855, 0.312935822, 1.030780455, 0.124008392, 0.080379696, 
    1.878184057, 1.149793494, 1.844110919, 0.770903793, 0.740968218, 
    1.044931412, 1.318952613, 1.572090973, 2.152665612, 12.43535565, 
    12.51943466, 1.267239978, 12.48758338, 2.508690354, 2.460034411, 
    22.8344909, 8.323447463, 6.982107015, 21.4812216, 26.99766616, 
    3.2419105, 8.157506358, 11.82812154, 2.336253438)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
#Order the way we want the plot top to bottom 
Zoop_df_Ab$Class <- factor(Zoop_df_Ab$Class, levels=c("Rotifera","Cladocera","Cyclopoida","Calanoida"))

#order the way we want legend top to bottom
classes <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Class      , ~fill      , ~pattern    , ~pattern_angle, ~order
  , "Calanoida", "#333D47"    , "none"      ,              0,      1
  , "Cyclopoida"  , "lightgrey", "crosshatch"      ,              30,      2
  , "Cladocera" , "lightgrey"    , "none",             0,      3
  , "Rotifera" , "white" , "stripe"    ,             45,      4
)

##New 

Ab_plot_Zoop  =  ggplot(Zoop_df_Ab,                         # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
                        aes(x = factor(Lake),
                            y = Value,
                            fill = Class)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack", width = 0.6, size = 0.5) +
  geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill=NA, size=0),
        text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 100)) +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance (%)"))) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(Season, levels=c('July','August','September'), ), nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside") +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot', 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.15, 0.15)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = setNames(classes$fill, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern_angle, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Class),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "black",
  )+ theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1), axis.text = element_text(face="bold"), text = element_text(size = 10))

Ab_plot_Zoop
```

The `size =` inside `geom_bar` is usually used to change the size of the bar outlines but it is not working properly. Is there another way to control the thickness of the bar outlines?

Current output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
```

As directed in the warning, just use the `linewidth` parameter instead of `size`! Warnings are meant to give help and direction, so pay attention to them.

Your code should look like:

```
# start of ggplot code
geom_bar(stat = "identity",
    position = "stack", width = 0.6, linewidth = 0.5) +
# rest of ggplot code
```

Here's a much simpler example to demonstrate:

```
library(ggplot2)

iris |>
    ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_bar(linewidth = 1, color = "red")
```

Comment: That will not fix the issue. While `size=` is deprecated and one should use `linewidth=` instead, `size=` still works, i.e. under the hood ggplot2 renames`size=` as `linewidth=` but throws a warning.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is simply that you have to set the `size=` or `linewidth=` in `geom_col_pattern` (the `geom_bar` is actually not needed and is not displayed at all as the `geom_col_pattern` is plotted on top of it).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(
  Zoop_df_Ab, # Draw barplot with grouping & stacking
  aes(
    x = factor(Lake),
    y = Value,
    fill = Class
  )
) +
  # geom_bar(
  #   stat = "identity",
  #   position = "stack",
  #   width = 0.6, size = 0.5
  # ) +
  # geom_vline(data = dat_vline, aes(xintercept = xintercept), lineend = "square") +
  # geom_hline(data = dat_hline, aes(yintercept = yintercept), lineend = "square") +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Class),
    pattern_size = .05,
    pattern_density = .1,
    pattern_spacing = .02,
    pattern_fill = "black",
    color = "red",
    linewidth = 2
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.15, 0.15)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = setNames(classes$fill, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  scale_pattern_angle_manual(
    "Class",
    values = setNames(classes$pattern_angle, classes$Class),
    breaks = classes$Class
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  facet_wrap(
    ~ factor(Season, levels = c("July", "August", "September"), ),
    nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x"
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
    axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"), 
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "line"),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA, size = 0),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  labs(x = "", y = expression(paste("Relative Abundance (%)")))
```

[image]